# Using libsodium in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, cryptography, php-7, libsodium, php-7.2

In PHP 7.2 libsodium should be part of PHP core. Is any entry in `php.ini` file required to make it work or maybe it should work out of the box?

I'm trying with **PHP Version 7.2.0beta2** and functions like `sodium_version_string()` or `sodium_compare` are unknown. I'm using PHP docker box (**7.2-rc-fpm**)

Just in case - I haven't installed any PECL extension because as far as I understand it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It might be compiled without sodium support: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/934cfa35f8c3946b812739e4ed5afe0f456610eb/ext/sodium/config.m4#L5   Please check `php -i` whether it is enabled or not.

Answer (score 3):

In order for this extension to be built, the library has to be present, as long as the development headers.

In addition, the `--with-sodium` option has to be given to the `./configure` script before compiling PHP.

If you don't want to recompile PHP, you can install the PECL version, which offers the exact same API (I usually update the PECL version first, and then port the changes to the PHP source code).